# How can I check if a value is present in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following in javascript:

```
 var colors = ["dark", "light"];

 if (localStorage.themeColor) {
```

How can I modify this to not only check that localStorage.themeColor is set but also 
to check that it is one of the two values in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in conjunction with your existing check for themeColor:

```
if(localStorage.themeColor && colors.indexOf(localStorage.themeColor) > -1) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say something like:

```
var colors = ["dark", "light"];

if (localStorage.themeColor && colors.indexOf(localStorage.themeColor) != -1) {
```

For indexOf see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FindexOf

Comment: This won't work. You've got an error in your indexOf check and your missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
{
if(localStorage.themeColor==colors[i])
{
alert(colors[i]);
}
else{
alert("colors not set");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`colors.indexOf("dark") !== -1`

indexOf returns -1 if the argument passed does not exist in colors

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this

```
var colors = ["dark", "light"];

if (localStorage.themeColor && colors.indexOf(localStorage.themeColor) > -1) {
    // Your Code...
}
```

I tested it in the case of `localStorage.themeColor == light` and `localStorage.themeColor is undefined`

Answer (score -1):

you should create a prototype like this

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(elem)
    {
       for (var i in this)
       {
          if (this[i] == elem) return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

And your array here

```
var colors = ["dark", "light"];
```

Finally call the function using `colors.contains("dark")` // this will return true

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote this because you're basically rewriting an existing function.

Comment: existing function you mean contains() ?

Comment: No, indexOf (as linked to in multiple answers here) does exactly this